# Setup and Deployment of python

Tags: python, django, setup-deployment

How to set up and deployment of python project?.My python path  in `C:\Python33`.I created a simple python application in `C:\Users\PC9\myapp`.How to install my python app on other system?.For my i created a `setup.py` and also my project tree like

```
Myproject
  Myproject
  app
  setup.py
```

Which path is used for my python project installation?
I used `python 2.7.3` and `django 1.5.5`

Comment: Please check this chapter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/ - if you have any questions, please be specific.

Comment: You used 2.7.3 and your Python path is C:\Python33?

Comment: yes,python 2.7.3 and path is C:\Python33